# Remove gaps between DIVs

Tags: html, css

This website is designed for tablets, and the problem is, when the window is resized, there is a margin, or some kind of gap between the three divs and their background images (they are stacked vertically). The image is a chalkboard in three pieces. The middle div needs to be able to expand with text input while the top is static and bottom piece gets pushed down as the middle expands.

Link to site:

url no longer available

CSS for the Divs so far

```
.blackboard1 {
background:url(../img/chalkboardtop.png);
height: 28px;
background-size:100% auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
z-index:9999999;
}

.blackboard2 {
background-size:100% auto;
background:url(../img/chalkboardmiddle.png);
background-size:100% auto;
background-repeat:repeat-y;
z-index:-9999999;
padding-top:28px;
padding-bottom:35px;
overflow:visible;
}

.blackboard2 p{
color:#fff;
background-color:none;}



.blackboard3 {
background-size:100% auto;
background:url(../img/chalkboardbottom.png);
height: 28px;
background-size:100% auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
z-index:9999999;    
}

#blackboardWrap {
background:url(../img/chalkboardmiddle.png); */
background-size:100% auto;
background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

One solution I used which i don't think is optimal, is to have the image that serves as the middle image, also serve as a fourth background that wraps around all three divs and sits behind them. This way when there are "cracks" between the divs, you can't notice as much. Using this solution it seems like it will add to loading time and also doesn't quite look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gaps are because of margins:

```
p {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

please remove those margins and see if gaps are still there or not.

Comment: He should also add `padding-left: 20px;` and `padding-right: 20px;` but yes, I agree with your answer.